# How to get predictions in NLME at the correct level instead of NAs?

Tags: r, nlme

I have a simple experiment (here is some made-up data) with 3 locations ("loc"), blocks within locations ("block"), a set of 8 treatments ("treat), and a response variable ("response"). An exponential plateau function was adjusted to this data (response as a function of treat) and the NLME function was used to analyze the whole experiment using mixed models. The parameters of the exponential plateau function is considered the fixed part while loc and block are random.

My problem is with the prediction of the model. I am not able to get the prediction for the response to the treatments at the loc level. I am able to get it to the population level (fixed effect), but got all NAs for the prediction when try to do it a the loc level. Is there something wrong with the way I set the "levels= " option?

Here is my made up data

```
#dataframe
loc <- c("Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3")
block <- c("Block_1", "Block_2", "Block_3", "Block_4")
treat <- as.numeric(c("0","40","80","120","160","200","240","280"))
empty <-expand.grid(treat,  block, loc)
response <- as.numeric(c(7064,  9250,   12306,  13549,  13300,  13973,   
                         14749,  14086, 7680, 11426, 12874,  12556,  14274,  14289,  15295,  14587, 
                         8445,   11588,  13223,  13322,  13508,  13616,  13747,  13352, 9454,     
                         11104,  12462,  13373,  14060,  14576,  14133,  14427, 5463, 8689,  10194,   
                         11996,  13475, 12544,   12856,  11557, 5251, 7537,  12074,  12438,  12120,   
                         11312,  9908, 12841, 4643,  7513,   10499,  12423,  12177,  12545,  12876,   
                         13047, 4992, 9458, 1071,    12104,  13552,  12602,  13210,  14428, 4061, 
                         3959,   5871,   8016,   9472, 11554,    12525,  12636, 4598, 7717,  7274,    
                         8476,   9433,   10768,  10275,  8200, 4862, 5727,   6468,   8532,   10662,   
                         12054,  12227,  12672, 5218, 7878, 8238, 10303, 10331,  13337,  12877,   
                         11661))
resp.data <- cbind(empty, response)
resp.data <- resp.data[c("Var3", "Var2", "Var1", "response")]
names(resp.data) <- c("loc", "block", "treat", "response")
```

Here is the function and the model fit

```
#exponential plateau function
expfunc <- function(beta0, beta1, beta2, x){
        y <- beta0 * (1 - exp(-exp(beta1) / 1000 * x + beta2))
        return(y)}

# model fit with blocks and locations as random effects
library(nlme)
exp.loc_block <- nlme(response ~ expfunc(beta0, beta1, beta2, treat),
                      data = resp.data,
                      fixed = list(beta0 ~ 1, beta1 ~ 1, beta2 ~ 1),
                      random = list(loc = pdDiag(beta0 + beta1 + beta2 ~ 1),
                                    block = pdDiag(beta0 + beta1 + beta2 ~ 1)),
                      start = c(12000, 3, -1),
                      na.action = na.omit,
                      verbose = F)

summary(exp.loc_block)

# This provides evidence that levels loc and block within loc are having random effects calculated
ranef(exp.loc_block)
```

And here is how I made prediction

```
#creation of the empty dataframe
#creation of the empty dataframe
xvals <- seq(min(resp.data$treat),max(resp.data$treat),length.out=100)
Loc.names.vector <- unique(resp.data$loc)
block <- c("Block_1","Block_2","Block_3","Block_4")
pframe.lp<-expand.grid(xvals, Loc.names.vector, block)
names(pframe.lp)[1]<-"treat"   
names(pframe.lp)[2]<-"loc"
names(pframe.lp)[3]<-"block"  
#prediction at location level (random effect)
pframe.lp$yield.exp <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe.lp, level=0)
pframe.lp$yield.exp <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe.lp, level=1)
pframe.lp$yield.exp <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe.lp, level=2)
```

Prediction with level=0 works fine for the prediction of fixed effects. Prediction with level=2 works fine for the prediction at block/loc random level 
Prediction with level=1 gives me NAs.. this would be the prediction at the loc level, which is the one I am most interested in.

Is there any mistake in the level option?

Here is the explanation of prediction using the nlme function 
https://rdrr.io/cran/nlme/man/predict.nlme.html

Comment: I don't see a block column in `pframe`. The `newdata` argument needs to be congruent with the original `data=` argument`.

Comment: Yes, that's right.. but I want the prediction at the loc level. Is that doable?

Comment: Sure, but you need to specify some level for `block`. It can all be the same level but it needs to be a value in the range of the original data.

Comment: Ok. Perfect. Last question. Will the result change if I use,  let's  say, block 1 instead of block for block level?

Comment: I would expect that it would change, assuming you meant "Block1" versus"Block2", i.e existing levels.. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: Because I was assuming I am asking for a prediction at the loc level, using the level =1 option. At the end, is not that I am doing a prediction at the loc level.. it is at the loc by block level. Right?

Comment: I just edited my question to include @42- suggestion of having blocks in the empty data frame. But I am still having the issue of NAs.

Comment: @42- Sorry!!! I messed up when copying from my actual code. Now there is a running and reproducible example. Level=0 means the prediction for the fixed effects. Please, consider re-open..

Comment: It was never closed. Takes 3 close votes this month (previously took 5.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing any NA's. Can you show the codes and sufficient output to document your issues? (I was instead using `levels=0:2` and looking at `str(pframe.lp)` and then getting this from `summary(pframe.lp$yield.exp$predict.loc)`:

```
> pframe.lp$yield.exp <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe.lp, level=0:2)
> 
> str(pframe.lp)
'data.frame':   1200 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ treat    : num  0 2.83 5.66 8.48 11.31 ...
 $ loc      : Factor w/ 3 levels "Loc1","Loc2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ block    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Block_1","Block_2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ yield.exp:'data.frame':  1200 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ loc          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Loc1","Loc2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ block        : Factor w/ 12 levels "Loc1/Block_1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ predict.fixed: num  5987 6188 6384 6575 6762 ...
  ..$ predict.loc  : num  7867 8125 8374 8613 8842 ...
  ..$ predict.block: num  7867 8121 8366 8601 8827 ...
 - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
  ..$ dim     : int  100 3 4
  ..$ dimnames:List of 3
  .. ..$ Var1: chr  "Var1=  0.000000" "Var1=  2.828283" "Var1=  5.656566" "Var1=  8.484848" ...
  .. ..$ Var2: chr  "Var2=Loc1" "Var2=Loc2" "Var2=Loc3"
  .. ..$ Var3: chr  "Var3=Block_1" "Var3=Block_2" "Var3=Block_3" "Var3=Block_4"
> summary(pframe.lp$yield.exp$predict.loc)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   4380    9219   11426   10928   13103   14279
```

That usage was not ideal. Adding a dataframe to an existing dataframe is bad R practice. Better would be:

```
pframe.lp$yield.exp <- data.matrix( predict( 
                                  exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe.lp, level=0:2) )
```

Comment: Perfect! The "level = 0:2" makes the trick. Thanks a lot @42- for your help and patience.